# How to hide text present inside search box?

Tags: javascript, css, tampermonkey

I have set a bookmark which has `-adult` word to search query, so that inappropriate results won't show up. Now, how do I hide `-adult` present in the search box?

Example:

[image: youtube screen capture]

My idea so far:

To use CSS to hide it then make another textbox to be seen, then add a few event handlers to sync the real search box with my fake search box.

> comments by @wOxxOm
>
> that's tricky to implement I suppose since google uses ajax and
> events, but probably it'll be possible to set a document **mutation**
> **observer** which will hide the stuff in the search box before it's shown

If the above method is not possible, then please suggest alternative for solving this problem.

Comment: You want full text to be hidden or just "Test" one???

Comment: @C-link Nepal just"Test" one. please tell me its doable.

Comment: just want to hide it that user can't see or remove and when inspected there won't be shown?

Comment: @C-link Nepal just want to hide it that user can't see, anything above is overkill.

Comment: Then it can be done just using css, use a blank div with background-color as of input box and overlay using absolute positioning...

Comment: you may also use a hidden input from which code will search but displaying input would be another...

Comment: I'm sorry, who is "Jared",did I miss anything?

Comment: Yeah, commented, but removed...

Comment: @C-link Nepal Absolute positioning,will it sync with "Test"?Like,if a user uses spacebar to move text.Just want to know is it reliable?.Thanks

Comment: Is `-adult` part of a query string that is passed in when the search is executed?

Comment: @Matt Smith `-adult` word is already attached to the search query,even before the user types anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `-adult` from the field and append it on the button click event. Example:

```
var keywordInput = $('input[name="-adult"]');
$('input[name="SearchButton"]').click(function() {
  window.location = 'http://example.com?kwd=' + encodeURIComponent(keywordInput.val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to programming but trying my best.Where do I add your code  in this [script](http://superuser.com/a/800331/357436) .I'm collecting answers little by little all over the forum.

Comment: The jQuery snippet above can be added as a separate <script> it added below your other JS code. It's just an example so you need to substitute the appropriate HTML markup with how your search item is coded.

Answer (score -1):

dont put the word you dont want them to see... use this code instead:

```
<?php
$dasearchstring = "I Want this text hidden";
$darealsearchstring = "Test".$dasearchstring;
?>
```

js code:

```
var dasearchstring = "I Want this text hidden";
var darealsearchstring = "Test"+dasearchstring;
```

dasearchstring is what the user searched; darealsearchstring is what is really searched. 
The text "Test" is the string that you want to prefix searches with.

*hope this clears it up!*

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to programming.Where do I implement your php code? A visual example will be nice.

Comment: PHP is not in any way related to this question.

Comment: i am giving a php example. this can also be modified to work with js. i will update answer